# how to fix ignoring DTS going backward warning

Tags: gstreamer, http-live-streaming, gstreamer-1.0

While running below gstreamer pipeline command i am keep on getting ignoring DTS going backward , facing tough time to fix thise warning . Can someone please help to fix this warning, in-terms of audio /video decoding i am not facing any issue

GSTREAMER PIPELINE COMMAND [**appsrc name=videosrc is-live=true block=true do-timestamp=true stream-type=0 format=time caps=video/x-raw,format=BGR,width=1920,height=1080,framerate=30/1 ! videoconvert ! x264enc tune=zerolatency ! mux. appsrc name=audiosrc do-timestamp=true format=time caps=audio/x-raw,format=S16LE,channels=2,rate=48000,layout=interleaved  ! audioconvert ! queue ! voaacenc ! aacparse ! queue ! mux. mpegtsmux name=mux ! queue ! hlssink location=/var/www/slot1/segment-%05d.ts playlist-location=/var/www/slot1/slot1.m3u8 max-files=10 playlist-length=5 target-duration=5**]

```
0:00:00.274315533  1111 0x7f51fc06dcf0 FIXME                default gstutils.c:3981:gst_pad_create_stream_id_internal:<videosrc:src> Creating random stream-id, consider implementing a deterministic way of creating a stream-id
0:00:00.274463655  1111 0x7f51fc06d2d0 FIXME                default gstutils.c:3981:gst_pad_create_stream_id_internal:<audiosrc:src> Creating random stream-id, consider implementing a deterministic way of creating a stream-id
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:638:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1108:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dsnoop.c:638:(snd_pcm_dsnoop_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1108:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1108:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> devInfo 2 48000 2
0:00:00.810182146  1111 0x7f51fc06ded0 FIXME               basesink gstbasesink.c:3145:gst_base_sink_default_event:<multifilesink0> stream-start event without group-id. Consider implementing group-id handling in the upstream elements
0:00:00.810414906  1111 0x7f51fc06dd90 WARN               mpegtsmux mpegtsmux.c:1284:mpegtsmux_clip_inc_running_time:<mux:sink_66> ignoring DTS going backward
0:00:00.810571173  1111 0x7f51fc06dd90 WARN               mpegtsmux mpegtsmux.c:1284:mpegtsmux_clip_inc_running_time:<mux:sink_66> ignoring DTS going backward
0:00:00.810638670  1111 0x7f51fc06dd90 WARN               mpegtsmux mpegtsmux.c:1284:mpegtsmux_clip_inc_running_time:<mux:sink_66> ignoring DTS going backward
0:00:00.810702713  1111 0x7f51fc06dd90 WARN               mpegtsmux mpegtsmux.c:1284:mpegtsmux_clip_inc_running_time:<mux:sink_66> ignoring DTS going backward
0:00:00.810760674  1111 0x7f51fc06dd90 WARN               mpegtsmux mpegtsmux.c:1284:mpegtsmux_clip_inc_running_time:<mux:sink_66> ignoring DTS going backward
0:00:00.842297487  1111 0x7f51fc06dd90 WARN               mpegtsmux mpegtsmux.c:1284:mpegtsmux_clip_inc_running_time:<mux:sink_66> ignoring DTS going backward
0:00:00.876042244  1111 0x7f51fc06dd90 WARN               mpegtsmux mpegtsmux.c:1284:mpegtsmux_clip_inc_running_time:<mux:sink_66> ignoring DTS going backward
0:00:00.939012033  1111 0x7f51fc06dd90 WARN               mpegtsmux mpegtsmux.c:1284:mpegtsmux_clip_inc_running_time:<mux:sink_66> ignoring DTS going backward
0:00:01.009470773  1111 0x7f51fc06dd90 WARN               mpegtsmux mpegtsmux.c:1284:mpegtsmux_clip_inc_running_time:<mux:sink_66> ignoring DTS going backward
0:00:01.078878028  1111 0x7f51fc06dd90 WARN               mpegtsmux mpegtsmux.c:1284:mpegtsmux_clip_inc_running_time:<mux:sink_66> ignoring DTS going backward
0:00:01.145503578  1111 0x7f51fc06dd90 WARN               mpegtsmux mpegtsmux.c:1284:mpegtsmux_clip_inc_running_time:<mux:sink_66> ignoring DTS going backward
0:00:01.208840176  1111 0x7f51fc06dd90 WARN               mpegtsmux mpegtsmux.c:1284:mpegtsmux_clip_inc_running_time:<mux:sink_66> ignoring DTS going backward
0:00:01.292051087  1111 0x7f51fc06dd90 WARN               mpegtsmux mpegtsmux.c:1284:mpegtsmux_clip_inc_running_time:<mux:sink_66> ignoring DTS going backward
0:00:01.355137842  1111 0x7f51fc06dd90 WARN               mpegtsmux mpegtsmux.c:1284:mpegtsmux_clip_inc_running_time:<mux:sink_66> ignoring DTS going backward
0:00:01.355221755  1111 0x7f51fc06dd90 WARN               mpegtsmux mpegtsmux.c:1284:mpegtsmux_clip_inc_running_time:<mux:sink_66> ignoring DTS going backward
0:00:01.415863009  1111 0x7f51fc06dd90 WARN               mpegtsmux mpegtsmux.c:1284:mpegtsmux_clip_inc_running_time:<mux:sink_66> ignoring DTS going backward
0:00:01.479122330  1111 0x7f51fc06dd90 WARN               mpegtsmux mpegtsmux.c:1284:mpegtsmux_clip_inc_running_time:<mux:sink_66> ignoring DTS going backward
0:00:01.520766275  1111 0x7f51fc06dd90 WARN               mpegtsmux mpegtsmux.c:1284:mpegtsmux_clip_inc_running_time:<mux:sink_66> ignoring DTS going backward
0:00:01.607511039  1111 0x7f51fc06dd90 WARN               mpegtsmux mpegtsmux.c:1284:mpegtsmux_clip_inc_running_time:<mux:sink_66> ignoring DTS going backward
0:00:01.679184317  1111 0x7f51fc06dd90 WARN               mpegtsmux mpegtsmux.c:1284:mpegtsmux_clip_inc_running_time:<mux:sink_66> ignoring DTS going backward
0:00:01.714954645  1111 0x7f51fc06dd90 WARN               mpegtsmux mpegtsmux.c:1284:mpegtsmux_clip_inc_running_time:<mux:sink_66> ignoring DTS going backward
0:00:01.777380293  1111 0x7f51fc06dd90 WARN               mpegtsmux mpegtsmux.c:1284:mpegtsmux_clip_inc_running_time:<mux:sink_66> ignoring DTS going backward
0:00:01.846492771  1111 0x7f51fc06dd90 WARN               mpegtsmux mpegtsmux.c:1284:mpegtsmux_clip_inc_running_time:<mux:sink_66> ignoring DTS going backward
```